# Measure local sockets speed?

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, unix

How to measure the speed of data exchange via `AF_UNIX` sockets? Is it possible to write some two bash scripts:

- First creates the socket, bind the socket to the local address, accept the connection and receive all data to `/dev/null`.
- The second one creates the socket, establish the connection with the already opened socket and spawn some device in `/dev` so it will be possible to measure the speed with `dd` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `netcat -U` to easily communicate over unix domain sockets. The `pv` command comes in handy when you want to know the speed at which data is moving through a pipe.

receiver:

```
nc -lU /tmp/socket > /dev/null
```

sender:

```
pv /dev/zero | nc -U /tmp/socket
```

In general, unix sockets are *really* fast. This clocked in at 170 MB/s on my old laptop, and 400 MB/s on my somewhat newer desktop.

Comment: I have measured the data rate with following commands: `while (true); do rm socket; nc -lU socket > /dev/null; done` and `dd if=/dev/zero bs=$BS | nc -U socket`. I have tried the following block sizes: `128, 256, 512, 1k, 2k, 4k, 8k, 16k and 32k`. The best perfomance was `201 MB/sec` with `16k` block size on my `i3` with `2GB` RAM.

Comment: Cool. I think the biggest limiting factor is how fast your RAM is.

Answer (score 2):

Although it isn't a script, this is some basic C code that I used to quantify the speed of socket data using standard TCP sockets (in case you really need to verify at the socket level and not just overall throughput). Basically, it writes out 1K...16M blobs of data in 1K chunks.

```
  for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
  {
     if ((fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) > 0)
     {
        timenode node;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &node.ts);
        if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == 0)
        {
           int n = 0;
           int wb = 1024<<i;
           while ((wb-n)>0)
           {
              n+=send(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
           }
        }
        do_ts(node.ts, wtn[i], wavg[i]);
        close(fd);
     }
  }
```

Ironically, I was able to see that on a 1Gbps link, I was able to get around 110 MB/s throughputs (125 MB/s is the theoretical max) until I got to sending 4+ MB of data...then it got throttled down to ~1 MB/s...because of back-pressure caused by an internal Ethernet switch problem.